# Mount docker.sock and use as custom user inside docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to mount "docker.sock" from the host system and use it with a custom user in the Docker container.

I create the user and add them to the docker group:

```
RUN groupadd docker
RUN usermod -aG docker dummy
USER dummy
```

In my docker-compose file I mount the docker.sock:

```
volumes:
  - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

If I run the docker container as root, i.e. comment out the line `USER dummy`. I can access the docker socket. But with my setup I get this error when I run e.g. `docker ps` inside the container as the dummy user.

```
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.39/containers/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: you need to create the user outside the container and add it to docker group and then in container map the uid and guid